# Application Class Lifecycle in Android

Tags: android, global

To maintain global variables, the Application class is extended. What happens to these variables when the application is put in the background and at some point, the OS wants to free up the resources? If the onTrimMemory() call is ignored, then does that mean that all of the variables are preserved? Unlike the Activity, which may have to rebuild some of its state.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To maintain global variables, the Application class is extended

You are also welcome to use classic Java static data members.

> What happens to these variables when the application is put in the background and at some point, the OS wants to free up the resources?

The only "resources" that "the OS wants to free up" will be your entire process. Your static data members or other singletons (like a custom `Application`, or your `ContentProvider` instances) will remain in memory until such time as Android terminates your process.

> If the onTrimMemory() call is ignored, then does that mean that all of the variables are preserved?

Yes, until such time as Android terminates your process.

Comment: At some point, the onCreate() of the Application object is called again, this must be when the entire process is terminated due to low memory condition, and all global variables stored in this Application object are freed up. In my case, ActivityA (the launch Activity) would initialize globals stored in the Application object and then starts ActivityB. When my app has been in the background for a while, the OS calls onCreate() of the Application object and then onCreate() of ActivityB. ActivityB relies on globals that are normally initialized by ActivityA, which is not called in this case.

Comment: @GaryKipnis: The problem, therefore, is in "ActivityA (the launch Activity) would initialize globals". Static data members, and the `Application` object, are meant to be caches, nothing more. Ideally, ActivityB can initialize those things itself, because they are simply lazy-initialized on first use. If there are things that ActivityB cannot initialize on its own, you are either going to need to detect this and re-route the user to ActivityA or otherwise mess with your task to get the user back to ActivityA.

Comment: I've added a check in all my Activities to see if ActivityA has been executed after onCreate() of the Application object, and if not, then simply start ActivityA to initialize everything, as it normally would upon application launch. And I am using Application object variables as "caches", but some initialization still needs to take place and ActivityA was the convenient place for this. A see a lot of apps do this, if the app has been in the background for a while, it will effectively restart and reinitialize everything when brought to foreground.

Comment: @GaryKipnis: It is not an unheard-of pattern. However, it does reduce the "feel" of multi-tasking to the user. Ideally, the user would not perceive a significant difference between returning to your app a minute, an hour, or a day after they left it. That will be impractical for some apps, but the closer you can get to it, the better your user satisfaction is likely to be.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Half of the time, the app is parked in ActivityB, so when this does occur, ActivityB is restarted automatically, there's not much else I can do about recovering the state for other Activities, as the sequence of ActivityA->ActivityB must take place before any other Activity is started. ActivityA->ActivityB transition is automatic, but ActivityB->OtherActivities is under user control and it's too much work to make these transitions automatic upon restart. This condition is also very infrequent.